# What to do when my proposed edit is rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In a now deleted comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509330/), the OP said it is a homework from a friend. Then I edited the question to add homework tag, and the edit was rejected.  I think this is my own fault for not giving enough explanations in the edit.

As this is not the first time my edit is rejected, I wonder whether there is a way to have some sort of communication with the people who reject. I could re-iterate my edit adding more explanations, but I do not really like to do so, it is a little like an edit war.

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is to include a comment in your description of the edit when you propose it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there was some agreement that the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag should only be toggled by the original poster. I guess that's the reason for the rejection.

So probably it's better first to add a comment asking the OP for adding the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag by himself. If this doesn't work, edit the question accordingly, but make a clear statement in the edit description that the OP said it is homework.

Comment: Not quite...the tag wiki says "Please do not add this tag to questions by other people unless they explicitly say that their question is part of their homework." So Cantlog was entirely correct to edit it in. That said, there is no harm in asking the OP first.

Comment: I'm quite sure this part of the tag wiki was formulated more restrictively in the past. So the reviewer might have been following that older guideline that only the OP should toggle the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: Looking through the tag history, it has been on the tag excerpt since January 6th 2012, but has only been on the main tag since March 3rd 2013 (edited in by yourself, I might add!).

Comment: @user1729: I was one of those who rejected the edit, and iirc, the comment in question said that the OP encountered the problem in a *friend's* homework assignment. I did not feel that this qualified as such an explicit statement.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ah, yes, I seem to have overlooked that sentence in the question. In that case, the sentence saying that Cantlog was correct should be removed from my above comment (which is impossible!). However, the actual point of the comment remains.

Comment: @user1729: Somehow I can't manage to look at the edit history. Well possible that it was me. But the "only by OP" thing certainly wasn't my idea originally. I think I had seen it in some discussion on meta before.

Comment: @azimut Sorry, that wasn't meant as a criticism, I just found it interesting :-) The excerpt history is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/27039/revisions), the main history is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/27038/revisions). The sentence was originally due to [t.b.](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b). I think it has been discussed on meta before, but I cannot find where (although I have not looked hard).

Comment: @user1729: Yeah, it's interesting! And showing me quite plainly how bad my memory is. Now I'm getting what you already said: The guideline was already in the excerpt, and I added it to the full tag wiki. That makes sense.

Comment: @CameronBuie: my point is not whether my proposed edit was acceptable or not, this is not a big deal. I would just like to have some possibility to dialog. Anyway I will stop editing other's posts as long as I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Cantlog Don't do that - keep editing! If something gets rejected it is no big deal.

Comment: @Cantlog: I couldn't agree more with user1729! Please do keep editing when you see a problem. We all get our edits rejected now and agaim--and at high rep, we get our edits rolled back. Don't let it discourage you.